# Кастомный select на Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular

Делаю простой селект на Angular.

```
  <div class="select">
    <div (click)="showItem()">{{value}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="visible">
      <div #ref (click)=select(ref) class="option" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Показываю и прячу выпадающий список так:

```
  showItem() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
```

Но он срабатывает только при клике на выдадающем списке. Как закрыть селект при клике вне селекта? Слушать весь документ наверное нерационально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой, быстрый и декларативный вариант - создать кастомную директиву:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[appOutsideClickListener]' })
export class OutsideClickListenerDirective {
  @Output()
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public click(target: HTMLElement): void {
    const clickedInside = this.host.nativeElement.contains(target);

    if (clickedInside) {
      return;
    }

    this.clickOutside.emit();
  }
}
```

Добавить в декларации модуля и использовать следующим образом:

```
<div class="select" appOutsideClickListener (clickOutside)="showItem()">
  ...
</div>
```

Либо же применяете директиву к вашему дочернему элементу, я не знаю просто вашей структуры.

Comment: Спасибо! Пишет ошибку - Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.

Comment: @Lex, обновил ответ

Comment: В консоли выводит TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: покажите как вы используете эту директиву?

Comment: Так как Вы написали - добавил в первую строку :
<div class="select" appOutsideClickListener (clickOutside)="showItem()">

Comment: добавьте в директиву конструктор и сделайте `console.log(this.host.nativeElement)` - что выведет?

Comment: constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    console.log(this.host.nativeElement);
  }

Comment: Ничего не выводит

Comment: такого быть не может, у вас ленивая загрузка или обычный роутинг? куда вы добавили директиву?

Comment: Обычный, все по обычной схеме - добавил директиву в app.module в declarations

Comment: а можете показать полный шаблон - где именно находится `div class=select` ?

Comment: Это тестовый пример у меня - все лежит в app.component.html
Больше кода там никакого нет

Comment: если вас затруднит можете создать stackblitz с тем что вы сделали? мне будет так легче вам помочь

Comment: Спасибо большое! Мне просто нужно уже уходить. Я понял в каком направлении нужно смотреть)

Comment: @Lex, успехов! я вам просто скажу, что этот пример действительно рабочий, я его использую на своем проекте, если будут вопросы еще - создайте stackblitz

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!)

Comment: Создал https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n7s5ca
При клике вне селекта, срабатывает список

Comment: у вас просто один метод на все случаи жизни, создайте два отдельных метода - `showSelect() { this.visible = true }` и `hideSelect`, как раз хайд нужно слушать в `(clickOutside)="hideSelect()"`, а `showSelect` вместо `showItem`

Comment: А, точно, спасибо!!